# Create new variable in python for each iteration

Tags: python, dummy-variables

I have two different dataframes like below.

[image]

And I need to make a dataframe like the following one.

[image]

Can you please help on how to that in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The operation above is called cross-join. So one way to do it is like this. Let your first dataframe called df1 and the second one called df2.

```
df1['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0
df_joined = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', key='key')
df_joined.drop('key', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

This should work.